Can I still enter the US with this Parolled stamp on my C1d visa and how to check if my visa is cancelled or not?
I was working on a cruise and had an early signoff and had a security escort and got a stamp which says

Purpose:- DT-PAROLE TO DEPART FOREIGN

My two questions are:

Can I still go back into the US for ship line with this stamp or is it going to be an issue?
Can I get F1 visa even though I have a stamp that says "parole" on my C-1/D as I am looking forward to study there?


Can you clarify: On what date did this happen? Do you have a valid C-1/D visa, and what are its dates of validit? Were you still employed when you left the ship?

An entry stamp (and I-94) detailing how you were allowed to enter on your last stay applies to that stay only. Once you left the US, your stay was finished.
The next time you seek entry, you will be doing so on the basis of a valid visa. How you entered on your last stay has no direct bearing on your next entry. Do you have a valid visa? (If the same circumstances as your last entry apply, they might parole you again instead of admitting you on a visa, but parole is not something you can count on. The fact you were paroled last time does not mean you will be paroled again.)
If you have an unexpired visa, it was not visibly marked cancelled, and you did not stay past the time granted on your I-94 during your last stay, your visa is still valid, and you can use it to seek entry on your next entry if you are otherwise eligible to enter on that status.
Yes, you can try to get an F1 visa to study.
